# Using a bootstrap attribute, but enable to read the path for a local image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Using bootstrap 4, I'm trying to target an image on my local drive in the `class="carousel-item"` with the following attributes: `style ="background-image: url('../lesson.jpg' )`. It is not working. The style attribute doesn't consider `('../lesson.jpg')` as a working path.

Comment: In `url('.. /lesson. jpg' )` you've got a space between `..` and `/lesson` and between `lesson.` and `jpg` That could be the reason.

Comment: Actually, I didn't add any spaces in my coding. The spaces I have in the question above is a mistake I need to get rid of. I appreciate your help. ☺️

Comment: Hmm well the CSS looks alright so it sounds like it could be something else. Try opening up the developer console in your browser (F12 on most browsers). Does it show any errors? Also, does the image show up if you use an img element with the src set to the same url?

Comment: Problem solved, I think the problem was the version of bootstrap I was using as as soon as I changed the version the problem was solved.